# Graph diameter of the omnitruncated $E_8$ polytope

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, convex-polytopes, polytopes

What is the graph diameter of the 1-skeleton of the omnitruncate of the $E_8$ family of uniform 8-polytopes?

Answer (score 3):

Since the 1-skeleton of this polytope is just the Cayley graph of the Coxeter group $E_8$ w.r.t. the usual set of generators, this diameter should equal the length of the [longest element](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_element_of_a_Coxeter_group) in the group, which is 120 according to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/594010/415941).